# Getting a type or wrapper if the type is primitive

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a sorting method that would receive an array and a comparator for its elements as input. But an argument for an interface in java cannot be a primitive type, so for an array of elements of type `int`, a `Comparator<Integer>` is needed, not a `Comparator<int>`. In the case of an array of objects, my prototype looks like this:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, java.util.Comparator<T> c) {
    ...
}
```

In this case , the situation is as follows:

```
sort(new Integer[10], new IntegerComparator()); // compiled
sort(new int[10], new IntegerComparator()); // not compiled
```

where

```
public class IntegerComparator implements java.util.Comparator<Integer> {
    public CountingComparator() {}
    public int compare(Integer l, Integer r) { return l.compareTo(r); }
}
```

Is there a way in java to get a wrapper over `T` as a type if `T` is primitive and `T` otherwise?

Comment: T cannot be primitive

Comment: That is a reason we have IntStream instead of using Stream

Comment: You could overload the method ...

Comment: I understand that the `Comparator<Integer>` can compare two `int` without any problems. But I don't really understand how to make sorting of both primitive and complex types possible with one function, so as not to write the same code twice.

Comment: If providing one function was possible, do you think they would have added [18 `sort` methods to `Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) (not counting the parallel ones)?

Comment: Even if JLS technically allowed that - the compiler would have to resort to boxing your `primitive[]` array to a respective `wrapper[]` array (e.g. `int[]` to `Integer[]`) anyway since any generic type is not a primitive by definition. So, you can just do that conversion yourself (`int[]` to `Integer[]`) right before calling sort as this is effectively identical to what the compiler would do if the `sort(T[] a, Comparator<T> c)` was allowed to accept primitive arrays